# CMake how to verify that a loop was auto-vectorized

Tags: c++, cmake, auto-vectorization

All C++ compilers that support vectorization allow some report (*) being emitted to verify if a loop was vectorized, each with their own compilation flag and format in the vectorization report.

I can enable the corresponding flag and visually inspect the report to check if a loop that I expect to be auto-vectorized was indeed auto-vectorized.

I would like to incorporate in my CMake build a step that checks this automatically and fails the build if it didn't auto-vectorize.

How can I do this using CMake?
Is there anyone that has solved this problem already, somehow?

Thanks in advance

(*)
MSVC https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/qvec-report-auto-vectorizer-reporting-level?view=msvc-160

gcc https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html

clang https://llvm.org/docs/Vectorizers.html#diagnostics

Comment: ¿When was the last time something in cmake worked out of the box? Perhaps you'll need to add some custom command.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll complete the question.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to incorporate in my CMake build a step that checks this automatically and fails the build if it didn't auto-vectorize.
>
> How can I do this in CMake?

Applying [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) in steps:

1. Create an algorithm that can detect if the program was "auto-vectorized".

   - You can use some output from the compiler generated with special options, why not.
   - You could also dissasemble the code and find "the loop" and check for some instructions or syntax.
2. Then write a portable program that does implement that algorithm, preferably in some portable language.
3. Add a custom target to cmake configuration to run the check that could look like the following:

```
add_executable(final_exe sources.c...)
 
add_exececutable(check_if_vectorized sources.c...) # if compiled, choose your own language
add_custom_target(check_if_final_exe_is_vectorized
     COMMENT "Check if final_exe was vectorized"
     COMMAND $<TARGET_FILE:check_if_vectorized> $<TARGET_FILE:final_exe>
     DEPENDS $<TARGET_FILE:check_if_vectorized> $<TARGET_FILE:final_exe>
)
```

You could also add the check with `add_test` and have it run like a test.

> Is there anything that works out of the box?

No.

Comment: How can I pipe the output of compiling (that contains the vectorization report) to my custom command?

Comment: Write a program that takes the output of a program and passes it to a custom program. Typically that's shell job, and you do `sh -c 'command1 | command2`' So use shell if it's available  that `COMMAND sh -c '"$@" | command2' -- $<TARGET_FILE:check_if_vectorized> $<TARGET_FILE:final_exe>`. Because of `set -o pipefail` pitfalls, I would use a temporary file in between one program and another.